# Show that a linear transformation on $\Bbb R^{2n}$ preserves the symplectic form $\Omega$ if and only if $A^T \Bbb J A = \Bbb J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Hope everyone is well.

I'm really needing some help with this question I've been doing for the matrix groups course I'm taking.

Consider the skew-symmetric billinear form (on the vector space $\Bbb R^{2n}$ defined by $$\Omega(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_iy_{n+i} - x_{n+i}y_i)   $$ and $$\Bbb J:=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \mathbf 1 \\ \mathbf{-1} & 0\end{bmatrix} \in SL(2n,\Bbb R)$$

Show that a linear transformation (on $\Bbb R^{2n}$) $x \mapsto Ax$ preserves the symplectic form $\Omega$ if and only if $A^T \Bbb J A = \Bbb J$ (i.e the matrix $A$ is symplectic).

I know that the mapping is preserved if $\forall x,y \in \Bbb R^{2n}$ and $A \in \Bbb R^{2n\times2n}$ $$\Omega(Ax,Ay) =\Omega(x,y)$$

But I'm at a loss as to how to calculate $\Omega(Ax,Ay)$. In particular, how can the skew-symmetric form be realized as a matrix? I think it might be the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 & \mathbf 1 \\ \mathbf{-1} & 0\end{bmatrix} \in SL(2n,\Bbb R)$ but with this I'm not entirely sure how to go about proving that the form is preserved.

I have checked the internet thoroughly and can't seem to find too much detail on my issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your sum should start at $i=1$.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\Omega(x,y) = \langle -\mathbb{J} x,y \rangle = (-\mathbb{J} x)^ty = x^t \mathbb{J} y$, i.e., $\mathbb{J}$ is the matrix that represents the symplectic form in the standard basis. Therefore $$\Omega(Ax,Ay) = \Omega(x,y) \quad\forall x,y\iff x^t(A^t \mathbb{J}A)y = x^t \mathbb{J} y\quad \forall x,y \iff A^t \mathbb{J} A = \mathbb{J}.$$

Comment: Ah, that note was really informative. Wasn't figuring it like that in my head. Thanks so much!